# msgraph-sdk-php v2 how to get data from returned object?

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

im using msgraph-sdk-php v2.2.0 library to get last access of user to microsoft office365 service

```
$request = new UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration();
$request->queryParameters = UsersRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration::createQueryParameters();
$request->queryParameters->filter = "startswith(userPrincipalName,'".$data['user']."')";
$request->queryParameters->select = ['signInActivity'];

$user = $o365->users()->get($request)->wait();
```

everything works ok.

but getting data from $user object is painfull:

```
$user->getBackingStore()->enumerate()['value'][0]->getBackingStore()->enumerate()['signInActivity']->getBackingStore()->enumerate();
```

is there a simplier way to do that?

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `getValue()` to access array of users and `getSignInActivity()` on specific user.

```
$user->getValue()[0]->getSignInActivity();
```